# Is there anyway to redirect all existing controller for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

Is there anyway to redirect all existing controller action in ASP.NET MVC to a specific page (i.e. `Home/Login`) when a condition is false (i.e. session is dead, empty)?

If yes, how do you apply the code and where to put it in?

Comment: You need to implement custom action filter attribute and implement OnActionExecuting method. check session variable is null or not, if null then redirect to route - Home/Login. Use the attribute in Controller class. Refer -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803908/redirect-after-session-timeout-in-mvc-action-filter

Comment: Thank you, at least I have direction of what to do now.